# Python tkinter: Celsius in openweathermap API

Tags: python, tkinter

How to change fahrenheit (*F) into celsius (*C) with openweathermap API? I'm trying to create a program where you type a city name and you will receive the temp etc. and it should be displayed in celsius... but I can't figure out how to do it.
THX 4 any help.

CODE:

```
import tkinter as tk
import requests
hi = 500
wi=600
root = tk.Tk()

def test_fun(entry):
    print(entry)

def fr(weather):
    try:
        name = weather['name']
        des = weather['weather'][0]['description']
        temp = weather['main']['temp']

        fs='City: %s \nConditions: %s \nTemp (C*): %s' % (name, des, temp)
    except Exception:
        fs="That's error 404. Type correctly "

    return fs

def weather1(city):
    key='aba06543f5f70442cc5b3efe6674d2b4'
    url='http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather'
    **p={'APPID': key, 'q': city, 'units': 'imperial'}** 
    r= requests.get(url, params=p)
    w=r.json()
    label['text'] = fr(w)
    print(w['name'])
    print(w['weather'][0]['description'])
    print(w['main']['temp'])



canvas = tk.Canvas (root, height=hi, width= wi)
canvas.pack()  

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='#000080', bd=2,)
frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.1, relwidth=0.75, relheight=0.1, anchor='n') 

button = tk.Button(frame, text="GO", font=36, command=lambda: weather1(entry.get()))
button.place(relx=0.7, relwidth=0.3, relheight=1)                                        

entry=tk.Entry(frame, font=30)
entry.place(relwidth=0.69, relheight=1)

frame2 = tk.Frame(root, bg='#000080', bd=2)
frame2.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.25, relwidth=0.75, relheight=0.6, anchor='n')

label=tk.Label(frame2, bg='#00CED1')
label.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: All you need to do to get an answer to this question is read the openweathermap api documentation.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you could approach this. First you could maybe pass 'metric' in your parameters to the api instead of 'imperial'.

Or you could implement a function that converts the answer you are getting from farenheit to celsius using the formula. `celsius = (fahrenheit - 32) * 5/9`.

Or you could just convert it in line in your program here:

```py
print(w['weather'][0]['description'])
print(w['main']['temp'])
```

change to something like:

```py
print(w['weather'][0]['description'])
celsius = (w['main']['temp'] - 32) * 5/9
print(celsius)
```

Personally I'd go for function definition option.